# window.FileReader not working in Mobile Browser

Tags: javascript, mobile

I am using the following code:

```
document.getElementById('design-upload').onchange = function (e) {
    if(window.FileReader) {
        //something ..
    }
}
```

It's working fine for desktop browsers, but when I click/tap on the button in mobile browsers it doesn't work.

Is there any alternative or solution which can work for both mobile browsers and desktop browsers as well?

Comment: on which mobile you are testing it?

Comment: Which mobile browser(s) are you using? While `FileReader` is relatively new, it [should be supported in all current non-iOS browsers](http://caniuse.com/filereader), but support in some of these browsers is only in the most recent version.

Comment: ...it's also supported in all current iOS browsers

Comment: @RayNicholus Derp, it's Monday. I didn't line up the "Opera Mini" column correctly.